# Spark streaming from a File source

Tags: python, spark-streaming

i have two notebooks : streaming.ipynb and File.ipynb  (tools: spark3.2.1, colab notebook)
the streaming.ipynb:

```
import sys
from textblob import TextBlob
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import string
import re

#Emoji patterns
emoji_pattern = re.compile("["
         u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons
         u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
         u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols
         u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS)
         u"\U00002702-\U000027B0"
         u"\U000024C2-\U0001F251"
         "]+", flags=re.UNICODE)
# define stopwords
nltk.download('stopwords')
stopword = stopwords.words('english')
# import stemmer from nltk
ps = nltk.PorterStemmer()
# import lemmatizer from nltk
#wn = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()
# import lemmatizer from nltk
import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
wn = nltk.download('wordnet') #WordNetLemmatizer()
def abb(tweet):
    tweet = re.sub(r"im|i'm|iam", "i am", tweet)
    tweet = re.sub(r"he's", "he is", tweet)
    tweet = re.sub(r"she's", "she is", tweet)
    tweet = re.sub(r"that's", "that is", tweet) 
    tweet = re.sub(r"there's", "there is", tweet) 
    tweet = re.sub(r"what's", "what is", tweet)
    tweet = re.sub(r"where's", "where is", tweet) 
    tweet = re.sub(r"\'ll", " will", tweet)  
    tweet = re.sub(r"\'ve", " have", tweet)  
    tweet = re.sub(r"\'re", " are", tweet)
    tweet = re.sub(r"\'d", " would", tweet)
    tweet = re.sub(r"\'ve", " have", tweet)
    tweet = re.sub(r"won't", "will not", tweet)
    tweet = re.sub(r"don't", "do not", tweet)
    tweet = re.sub(r"did't", "did not", tweet)
    tweet = re.sub(r"can't", "can not", tweet)
    tweet = re.sub(r"it's", "it is", tweet)
    tweet = re.sub(r"couldn't", "could not", tweet)
    tweet = re.sub(r"wouldn't", "would not", tweet)
    tweet = re.sub(r"have't", "have not", tweet)
    return tweet


def getSubjectivity(text):
   return TextBlob(text).sentiment.subjectivity
  
 #Create a function to get the polarity
def getPolarity(text):
   return TextBlob(text).sentiment.polarity
  
def getAnalysis(score):
  if score < 0:
    return "Negative"
  elif score == 0:
    return "Neutral"
  else:
    return "Positive"

def main():
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PysparkStreaming")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 5)   #Streaming will execute in each 3 seconds
    lines = ssc.textFileStream('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/log/')  #'log/ mean directory name
    counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split("")) \
        .map(lambda x: x.lower())\
        .map(lambda x: re.sub(r"@[A-Za-z0-9]+", "", x))\
        .map(lambda x: re.sub(r"\\x[A-Za-z][0-9]+", "", x))\
        .map(lambda x: re.sub(r"\\u[0-9][A-Za-z]|\\U[0-9][A-Za-z]+", "", x))\
        .map(lambda x: re.sub(r'&amp;amp;', '&', x)) \
        .map(lambda x: re.sub(r"b[\s]+", "", x)) \
        .map(lambda x: re.sub(r"https?:\/\/t.co\/[A-Za-z0-9]+", "", x)) \
        .map(lambda x: abb(x)) \
        .map(lambda x: re.sub("[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+", "",x)) \
        .map(lambda x: re.sub('[0-9]+', ' ', x))\
        .map(lambda x: emoji_pattern.sub(r'', x) )\
        .map(lambda x: "".join([char for char in x if char not in string.punctuation])) \
        .map(lambda x: re.split('\W+', x)) \
        .map(lambda x: " ".join(x))\
        .map(lambda x: [word for word in x if word not in stopword])\
        .map(lambda x: getPolarity(x))  
    counts.pprint()
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and File.ipynb:

```
from random import randint
import time

"""
This is use for create 30 file one by one in each 5 seconds interval. 
These files will store content dynamically from 'lorem.txt' using below code
"""


def main():
    a = 1
    with open('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/lorem.txt', 'r',encoding='latin-1') as file:  # reading content from 'lorem.txt' file
        lines = file.readlines()
        while a <= 30:
            totalline = len(lines)
            linenumber = randint(0, totalline - 10)
            with open('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/log/log.txt'.format(a), 'w') as writefile:
                writefile.write(' '.join(line for line in lines[linenumber:totalline]))
            print('creating file log{}.txt'.format(a))
            a += 1
            time.sleep(5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Notes:
in File.ipynb, i read lorem.txt which contains tweets and separate data in log.txt which is NULL but when you run the code it will be create log{1} contains a part of tweets, log{2} also and so on.... and streaming.ipynb stream from those logs each 5 seconds print the result, lorem.txt contains:

```
'A woman faces 100 lashes and up to seven years in prison because she was a VICTIM of RAPE in Qatar \n\nShe was told she could possibly avoid criminal charges if she married her attacker\n\n#FIFA22 #WorldCup2022 #Qatar2022 #Qatar' 
'#WorldCup2022 '
'i love my mother'
'it is so bad!'
'Black Stars technical team among 32 for 2022 Aspire Academy Global Summit\n\n-  \n\n.#Ghana #WorldCup2022 '
'New Episode 163 - The Business End out now!!! #WorldCup2022 #TorontoFC #RealMadridChelsea #LiverpoolVillarreal  #ManCityRealMadrid  #ARSMUN #ACMILAN #ChampionsLeague #uefachampionsleague \nOut now on all popular audio podcast platforms '
'Check out new work on my @Behance profile: "Edited" \n#edit #photoshop #photography #road #street #art #design #architect #amazon #quote #fun #amazing #EidMubarak #ukraine #putin #gold #oil #WorldCup2022'
'Can we talk about how bad the Al Rihla looks #WorldCup2022 '
'They should hire Mourinho as a consultant for the #WorldCup2022'
'@yuzi_chahal @imkuldeep18   The spin duo back with bang bang performance for representing franchise   Eagerly Waiting to see in India team behind the stump by Rishaph pant The selectors are very big problem to pick a players for #WorldCup2022\n#IPL20222'
'@DraganflyInc Draganflyer Commander can sanitize the entire 50,000 seater stadium in 4-6 hrs. The #WorldCup2022 in #Qatar2022 is slowly approaching. This drone could really help keep stadiums safe. Food for thought.\n\n#CovidIsntOver \n#GOPTaxScam \n#IMPEACHBIDENNOW \n#BTC \n#NFTs '
'NFT News \n\nTooneyChain: when NFTs invite themselves to the 2022 football world cup\n@TooneyChainNFT \n\n#WorldCup2022 #football #NFTs #NFTcollectibles '
'Mark my words. 3-1 USA over England this fall in the #WorldCup2022 . If we win, England has to call it soccer from now on.'
'you can as well use our services in projects that  are not permanent like @Containerhouse or #structures for #WorldCup2022 ,also for #camps ,#swimmingpool #parks #offices #dormitory'
'@bhogleharsha Than we need to forgot about @BhuviOfficial ?\n#ipl2022 #WorldCup2022'
'Ghana and Tunisia have been invited to take part in the Kirin Super Cup 2022, which will be hosted by Japan from Friday, June 10 to Tuesday, June 14, 2022, in the lead up to the #WorldCup2022 in Qatar.\n\nThe other 2 participants are hosts Japan and Chile #AfricanFootball'
'join us on TG for our game of the day!⚽️⚽️ The World Cup token team is rooting for a @Cristiano goal today! Good luck to both sides today! @ManUtd  @ChelseaFC  $WCT #WCT #WctArmy #WorldCup2022 #Qatar2022 #100xgem #BSC #BNB\xa0\xa0\xa0#BSCGem #BNBchain  #1000xgem #moonshot #ETH #CRO #BTC '
'@julietbawuah @tv3_ghana Wow, super talented player. Who knows, with him on #Qatar’s team they might just win the #WorldCup2022. #Qatar2022 #Fooball #games'
'@ForthHelena @thevinetway @jodyvance Jody are you a QA asset?\nCan Jody tweet about LGBTQ issues? Notable events from around the world ignored &amp; Jody is regurgitating CNn narratives?\nToo many ads not enough of what you want? SiriusXM commercial free entertainment.\n#Canucks \n#WorldCup2022\n#NFLDraft\n#TikTok '
'Congratulations, Danyel! You’re really having an impact in this field at just the right time!  This, alongside your new co-authored book on #Qatar &amp; the #WorldCup2022 , AND our @CIRSGUQ research project on the same subject! !  '
'Its the crypto world cup final and you are the manager.\nWhich front 3 are you going with?\n\n#xrp #vet #qnt #ada #zil #xlm #doge #btc #cro #eth #sand #luna #WorldCup2022\n#cryptocurrency'
'@yuzi_chahal I Would like to see KulCha Combination in  #WorldCup2022'
'It’s going to be scary, but not for us \n\n#Portugal #WorldCup2022 '
```

the error is shown below:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-bb31ef108289> in <module>()
     88 
     89 if __name__ == "__main__":
---> 90     main()

3 frames
/content/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o23.awaitTermination.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: An exception was raised by Python:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/pyspark/streaming/util.py", line 68, in call
    r = self.func(t, *rdds)
  File "/content/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/pyspark/streaming/dstream.py", line 170, in takeAndPrint
    taken = rdd.take(num + 1)
  File "/content/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1568, in take
    res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
  File "/content/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/pyspark/context.py", line 1227, in runJob
    sock_info = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
  File "/content/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/content/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (9557898acd7f executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 619, in main
    process()
  File "/content/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 611, in process
```

please how can i resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your code:

- As far as I understood you want to create a directory `/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/log/` with files following the `log<number>.txt` pattern. There seems to be a bug in this line:

```
with open('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/log/log.txt'.format(a), 'w') as writefile:
```

You don't actually create multiple files but overwriting the single `log.txt` file on every iteration due to the missing curly brackets in filepath.

- The second problem is much more complex: you are writing to the local filesystem in File.ipynb. `StreamingContext.textFileStream` accepts HDFS filepath as an argument. Please read the following chapter in the documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html

Comment: my problem is  how to extract sentiment from these tweets, so i want to do the three functions defined above (getSubjectivity, getPolarity, getAnalysis),i tried just the getPolarity fuction it works with small data but it calculate polarity for each word ( i want the polarity of all the tweet, how can i join the polarities???) also now when i try it with 23 tweets it doesn't work ( i didn't use hdfs storage).... did u understand the idea?